Save asset by kind with Dynamic Subfolder Path
Using Craft CMS 5 I have several fields where images and video's are separated fields.
Each field has a simple or dynamic subfolder path like
{{ owner.section.handle }}.
I wondered if it's possible to have a single field ('media' for example) that allows an image or a video to be uploaded, and its dynamic subfolder path is based on the kind of file. For example images would be saved in a folder 'images' and videos are saved in a folder 'videos'.
